# Combine unknown amount of lists, keep only common values

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to combine *N* lists and keep only the values that are in every single one of them. I don't know how many lists there are, so the code must be dynamic.

```
a_list = [(3, -1), (3, -1), (3, 0), (4, -1), (3, 1), (5, -1), (3, 2), (6, -1), (3, 3), (7, -1), (7, -1), (3, 3), (7, 0), (4, 3), (7, 1), (5, 3), (7, 2), (6, 3), (7, 3), (7, 3)]
b_list = [(-3, 3), (-3, 3), (-3, 4), (-2, 3), (-3, 5), (-1, 3), (-3, 6), (0, 3), (-3, 7), (1, 3), (-3, 8), (2, 3), (-3, 9), (3, 3), (3, 3), (-3, 9), (3, 4), (-2, 9), (3, 5), (-1, 9), (3, 6), (0, 9), (3, 7), (1, 9), (3, 8), (2, 9), (3, 9), (3, 9)]
a = set(a_list)
b = set(b_list)
print(list(a&b))
```

This code works perfectly for *a known number of lists*, but I don't know how many lists there are.

Note: "Unknown number of lists" means it depends on the values the script is ran with.

Edit: *N > 0*

Comment: Can there be zero lists? Because the below solutions fail for that. Plus it's not clear what the result should be then.

Comment: @StefanPochmann No, N > 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in `set` function  `intersection`:

```
print (set.intersection(*map(set, lists)))
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it doesn't require any additional libraries.

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich The other answer also doesn't require additional libraries. `functools` is part of Python's standard library.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I meant libraries as in something to be `import`ed

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce`

```
import functools
list_of_sets = [set(x) for x in list_of_lists]
intersection = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, list_of_sets)
```